# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE multiple rows, checking duplicate for each row

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, rows

The expected behavior of the following code is that for each row, it checks if there is a duplicate, if so, it updates instead of inserting. It does this for EACH row separately, meaning that finding a duplicate for a certain row will not result into UPDATE for all other rows that follow. The UNIQUE key is member_id.

```
INSERT INTO table 
  (member_id, member_name, stat1, stat2) VALUES 
    ('1', 'user1', '1411', '1410'), 
    ('15', 'user2', '177', '179'), 
    ('83', 'user3', '517', '832'), 
    ('184', 'user4', '805', '1165'), 
    ('304', 'user5', '708', '705')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  stat1 = VALUES(stat1), 
  stat2 = VALUES(stat2)
```

What this seems to do however, is UPDATE from the first moment it finds a duplicate key for member_id.

E.g. user2 already exists, so instead of INSERT, do UPDATE. But then it does UPDATE for user3, user4, user5 even though they might not exist. This causes the following error:

```
Unknown column 'user3' in 'field list'
```

How do I ensure that it checks for duplicate for EACH row and if there is no duplicate, insert?

EDIT:
A more accurate snippet of my query:

```
INSERT INTO reputation_p_month (member_id, member_name, january_2018_rep, acc_january_2018_rep) VALUES
  ('1', 'GreatJackal', '1411', '1410'),
  ('15', 'wetletus', '177', '177'), 
  ('83', 'strongandbald', '517', '517'),
  ('14375', 'Newer', '0', '0'), 
  ('14379', 'RobsenMeister', '0', '0'), 
  (14405, Griffin, 0, 0) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  january_2018_rep = VALUES(january_2018_rep), 
  acc_january_2018_rep = VALUES(acc_january_2018_rep)
```

With the following error in console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
>
> 'Debug Objects: Error updating records for REP: Unknown column 'Griffin' in 'field list''

Comment: Try to rewrite that without using "VALUES" but rather "SET" syntax. (one at a time)

Comment: Glad you figured it out - StackOverflow's "Syntax-Highligting" would have told you, that `Griffin` is considered a Column-Name rather than a value - If you had posted "real" code rather than pseudo-code - which was "correct by accident" (as assumed) - we could have helped you much faster .:-)

Comment: Yeah, my reason for using pseudo code was because the actual query is rather lengthy, I made the wrong assumption that the error wasn't in the provided values. My bad :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Query is perfectly fine and should exactly produce the result you are expecting.

The Error Message

```
Unknown column 'user3' in 'field list'
```

actually means, that your query is considering the `Value`: `user3` as `column` at some point.

From the query posted, we can't determine the problem, i'll guess you simplified / obfuscated the query in a certain way, but the postet example was correct by accident.

Check, if you are inserting your user value for `user3` enclosed by backticks, like

`user3`

instead of

'user3'

(Back-ticking is used for COLUMN names, not values, which then would produce exactly the error message you are facing)

[image]

Comment: I just edited my post with a more accurate snippet of my code (front and end part of the values). I think the last part is missing some single quotes lol...

Comment: Okay, working as intended now :) thanks for the help!

Comment: @JorenBroekema Delivering "Help" to "Help yourself" - that's the most valuable thing out there!